# PHP - Correct way to create variables from $_POST form submissions to avoid Undefined Index

Tags: php, post, isset

I am creating a contact form in PHP. On the PHP script I am using to process the email, I am defining variables based on the submitted form fields. All of these form fields are required, so they will always exist. Currently I am setting the variables like this:

```
$fName = $_POST['first-name'];
```

This works fine, but if I have error reporting turned on, I end up getting `Notice: Undefined index: first-name`

If I set up the variable like this, I don't get the undefined index:

```
if (isset($_POST['first-name'])) {
    $fName = $_POST['first-name'];
}
```

But it doesn't feel right to do this because I'm basically adding 2 lines of code for every input. Is this the only way to avoid the `Undefined index` error? What is the correct way to define these variables, especially knowing that they are all required fields, so they will always be "set?"

Comment: *"they are all required fields, so they will always be "set?""* No. No they won't. Do never trust a user input. The rendered HTML can be modified with F12 (and the `required`) can be removed.

Comment: If `first-name` is a text input or some other types, then it will always be set on form submit, but it may be `empty()` so check that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'd like to differ, trusting the user inputs (GET/POST/FILES etc) to any extent, is only gonna 'break break your', break break your heart.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib: What are you talking about? I'm not trusting anything or saying to trust anything.  What I'm saying is that for most form inputs they will be SET and pass the `isset` check even if they are `empty`, meaning no user input.  If they are _required_ they shouldn't be EMPTY. When I say required I'm not talking about the form field attribute, I'm talking about the dev/app requires data in them.

Comment: What I am saying is, "counting on a value to be present in a user input array like (`$_GET`/`$_POST`)" is a design fallacy in itself. There are a whole lot of reasons those keys could end up *not being* in the above variables, and what happens then? Can't list them down here though. You should know better. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But it doesn't feel right...

Yup, A man's gotta do what a man's gotta do.

All you can do is simplify it as

```
$fName = isset($_POST['first-name'])? $_POST['first-name'] : '';
```

If you are using `PHP > 7.x.x`, you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) which will provide the **same** result as above **and** was build specifically keeping this scenario in mind.

So I say this **wins** in terms of usability. Thanks @Cid for mentioning this.

```
$fname = $_POST['first-name'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Ahh... I now know why I wrote like that, I had used `empty()` for this answer and later realised that the inputs could be `0` so updated the answer and that changed the whole meaning.

Comment: @user13286 what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Cid I am using 7.2.10 locally and 7.0.31 on production

Comment: @user13286 then, the second statement I added will work too.

Comment: @Cid Very cool, anything to shorten my code is great and makes me a little less crazy. Thank you both for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of inputs it can still be tedious with a ternary.  There are many ways to do this.  One way is to define required fields and check that all are set:

```
$required = array('first-name', 'last-name');

if(array_diff($required, array_keys($_POST)) {
    //all required fields not set, die or redirect or something
}
// then use $_POST vars as normal
```

If you as the developer and the application require inputs to be set, then most fields (text, password, select, etc.) will be by default even if they are empty. To check if they are not set or if they are empty:

```
if(array_diff($required, array_keys(array_filter($_POST))) {
    //all required fields not set or empty, die or redirect or something
}
// then use $_POST vars as normal
```